# Swift: unzipping file

Tags: swift, zip

I’m trying to get `String` from txt file inside the zip file using native `libcompression` library. Actually I use the code from

- https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression/blob/master/Sources/DataCompression.swift.

At first, I was doing:

```
let zip = try? Data(contentsOf: "/.../test.zip")    
let tmp: Data? = zip?.unzip()
let txt: String? = String(data: tmp!, encoding: .utf8)
```

But how do I get the contents of zip file and how do I get data from certain txt file?

Comment: Find a library that is meant for extracting files from a standard zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZIP Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) supports accessing individual entries in ZIP archives.
You have to initialize an archive by passing a file URL to the `Archive` initializer.
Afterwards you can access a specific entry via subscripting:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var archiveURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
archiveURL.appendPathComponent("test.zip")
guard let archive = Archive(url: archiveURL, accessMode: .read) else  {
    return
}
guard let entry = archive["file.txt"] else {
    return
}
var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
destinationURL.appendPathComponent("out.txt")
do {
    try archive.extract(entry, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print("Extracting entry from archive failed with error:\(error)")
}
```

You can also directly access the contents of `entry` by using the closure based API. This allows you to process the entry without writing it to the file system first:

```
try archive.extract(entry, consumer: { (data) in
    print(data.count)
})
```

Comment: Actually I've done that with ZIP Foundation :) Thanks for your work, Thomas! One question to. I'm accessing the contents of file without writing to file system by: var fileData: Data = Data()
        
        do {
            try archive.extract(entry, consumer: { (data) in
                fileData += data
            })
        } catch {
            print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
        } Is there a some better way to get all data from file?

Comment: The library reads chunk-wise from the archive. So your closure that accumulates the read data looks good. There's currently no convenience method that reads all data in one.

Comment: Thomas, I have a little problem. let entry = archive["file.txt"] is not the same as let entry = archive["File.TXT"]. Can I fix it quickly not to be case sensitive?

Comment: The library performs a case sensitive compare during subscripting. You will have to provide the exact case. (Or try all variations)