# Extract Images from Zip Archive

Tags: swift, image, zip

**My starting point:**

I get a zip archive with some compressed images from an API. I want to show the pictures in a slideshow.

**The problem:**

After I successfully downloaded the zip archive as `Data` from `URLSession.shared.dataTask` and uncompressed it with `let decompressedData = try (data as NSData) .decompressed (using: .zlib)`, I got no further.

I know that I can use `UIImage(data: data)` to display an image from data.

But how do I get the individual data for the images from the decompressed data?

Thank you in advance,
Lucas

*PS: If I haven't explained it clearly or if you need further details, please just ask*

Comment: If your data set is already structured in some way you could use a for each loop to loop over your unzipped data set. But it would be helpful if you could provide some more information about the unzipped data.

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  Is the zip file a file archive, or just raw zipped data of a certain format?  If it's a file archive, this answer will probably start to point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064483/swift-unzipping-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution myself:

```
guard let archive = Archive(data: data, accessMode: .read) else {
    return
}

for entry in archive {
    
    var extractedData: Data = Data([])
    
    do {
        _ = try archive.extract(entry) { extractedData.append($0) }
        
        if let image = UIImage(data: extractedData) {
            self.images.append(image)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Zip Foundation is required for this to work. Thanks @jn-pdx for pointing in the right direction. After a litte bit of digging I found a way to create a `Archive` with memory data.